# Conectar 2 bases de Datos Sql y Oracle en Spring boots

Tags: java, sql, oracle, spring-boot, spring

quiero conectar mi proyecto a una base de dato de producción en Oracle y a la vez estoy trabajando con una base Sql , alguien me podría decir como es la configuración para usar las dos juntas? Gracias